# Python memory leaks on Slicing list and writing to database

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, python-asyncio

Im facing memory leaks when slicing the list repeatedly and writing in to database. Currently I'm consuming the data from some queue(suppose Redis queue) and add the consumed to in-memory buffer from thread1 and another thread slices the required data and writes it to postgres. here is the snipped below. As a sample input stream, I'm adding push data function which return required input

```
import threading
import asyncio
import time
import random
from external_node import setup
import gc


class Worker:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.batch_size = 500
        self.check_con = 0
        self.check_task = 0
        self.thread_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.counter = 0

    def push_data(self, pid):
        print(f"starting to prepare the data {time.time()} for {id} ")
        prep_data = []
        current_time = int(time.time() * 1000)
        for i in range(1, 1000):
            current_time = current_time + 500
            dp = {'data_type': 'process', 'process_id': pid, 'timestamp': current_time}
            data_point = {}
            tags = range(1, 1000)
            for each_data_point in tags:
                data_point[str(each_data_point)] = random.random()
            # print(type(id))
            dp["data"] = data_point
            prep_data.append(dp)
        return prep_data

    def stream_thread(self, event_loop):
        while True:
            if self.counter < 50:
                input_data = self.push_data('3')
                self.thread_lock.acquire()
                for index in range(0, len(input_data), self.batch_size):
                    value = input_data[index: index + self.batch_size]
                    self.data.append(value)
                self.thread_lock.release()
                if self.check_task == 0:
                    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
                        self.write_data_to_postgres('3',
                                                    'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:6543/test'),
                        event_loop)
                    self.check_task = 1
                    print('task submitted to loop')
                time.sleep(1)
                self.counter = self.counter + 1
            else:
                time.sleep(600)
                self.counter = 0

    async def write_data_to_postgres(self, connection_url):
        if self.check_con == 0:
            await setup(**{"db_uri": connection_url})
            print('connection established')
            self.check_con = 1
        while True:
            if len(self.data) > 0:
                self.thread_lock.acquire()
                required_batch = self.data.pop()
                self.thread_lock.release()
                print(f'writing records count {len(required_batch)} and total number of records {len(self.data)}')
                time.sleep(5)
                del required_batch
                gc.collect()
            elif len(self.data) < 0 and self.counter > 50:
                self.data.clear()
            else:
                # print(f'no records found ... Wating')
                await asyncio.sleep(0.05)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    worker = Worker()
    stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker.stream_thread, args=(event_loop,))
    stream_thread.daemon = True
    stream_thread.start()

    event_loop.run_forever()
```

The expectation is to release the memory after it's written, but it's piling up. Is this the correct way of doing it? or any other better way? any suggestions are welcome.

Observations :

1. if i remove the database call all the memory is getting cleared. i tried with multiple database packages everything result the same. i thought its happening because of some reference not clearing issue. do you have any idea on it ???
2. if I call two functions in sequential in single thread, some memory is getting released. but with multiple thread its going too much.
3. if I go with a single thread and whatever the slicing is happening in the write_data_to_postgres moved to stream thread and call the function to write to Postgres with required batch releases the full memory.So i feel its fully related to referencing. any thoughts on this will be help full

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm completely wrong because I do not fully understand every part of your code, but if your code just runs forever and ever at high speed the `self.data = self.data + input_data` could cause an issue, since it's basically a list extending itself constantly with another list of nearly 2000 items, the `remaining_buffer` most likely gets bigger each time.

Do You have the same issue without the saving to postgress? If this line `DataBaseModel.create(edge_connector=int('3'), data=required_batch)` use some kind of orm in the background, or something that requires to be flushed, don't forget to do that. I've experienced memory issues with database related calls before, because often they keep track of data in the database, which you might not need.

I hope I helped a bit, although I don't really understand the code

EDIT:
Do you realize that your self.data will continue to expand forever?
the line:

```
             for index in range(0, len(input_data), self.batch_size):
                value = input_data[index: index + self.batch_size]
                self.data.append(value)
```

Will in the first run create a list of 2. So basically now self.data is a list of 2 lists, containing 500 items.

```
                required_batch = self.data.pop()
```

this will pop out the last item and place it in required_batch.
Right now there will still be 1 list of 500 dictionaries in your self.data. Then the code repeats, now it will add another 2 lists, and pop one out. Your self.data has 2 lists now after the pop. The memory footprint of this one is ever expanding.

There is an error in your code, although not a syntax one:

```
            elif len(self.data) < 0 and self.counter > 50:
                self.data.clear()
```

This line is never triggered since the length of a list, or any iterable is never smaller than 0.

I'm not certain if this is the big memory issue, maybe it's not, but it's something you should be aware off. I sadly know nothing about threading, so I feel this is all I can do to try and help.

Comment: Can you try to use raw sql in your database call? This should bypass the internal storage of data / ORM functionality of your database library, and have a smaller memory footprint. Another issue could be that you're not flushing/committing to the database, causing an orm to save transaction information without it writing it away and releasing memory.

Comment: Thanks. yeah,i hav tried with raw sql as well.Im using gino ORM with asyncpg. it will do automatic commit/flushing.

Comment: thanks you so much, Looks like maybe the issue is with the ever-extending list. But at some point of time the list is getting clear(len of list is 0). but wont the memory allocated to that extended is not released ?? any possible solution for this will be more helpful.

Comment: for testing purpose, i have removed database operation and simulated the code such a way that first thread produces more and takes the break and second thread consumes little slower than first. expectation is memory should be cleared when first thread pauses and second thread processed all the elements.

Comment: I hav tried using linked list as well as dequeue, haven't seen much difference

Comment: i have updated the code without any dependency this will run show us the memory leak

Comment: sorry for late response, forgot I posted something on here, I made an edit